# java - duplicate class

Tags: java, class, netbeans

Confused as to why I get duplicate class error for the following code?

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package database_console;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;


/**
 *
 * @author davidsonr
 */
public class DBConnect {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    }
}
```

Netbeans highlights DBConnect  as red with duplicate class error.

Comment: Error is pretty clear, Is there any other class in the **same package** with same name ?? Yes, Right ?

Comment: Its the only class file in my project.  However it must conflict with a standard library class?

Comment: Not familiar with NetBeans, Can you please clean and build ?

Comment: I decided to rename the class and file DBConnectOne.  that solved the error.

Comment: That's an alternative. But you should question everything, Try to find why it's happened. I'm sure you'l learn something :) Good luck with project.

Comment: clean build may solve your problem, you will learn something new

Comment: In my case. i only have one class in the package. so i change the name of the package, but still i don't understand why this happend...

Answer (score 74, accepted):

This is a known issue with netbeans [BUG 226360](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=226360)

it might help to clear Netbeans cache:

Go to `Help` -> `About` and you will see

**Cache directory:** Path\to\Directory

Close NetBeans, go to specified directory and delete everything.

Comment: how should I do this in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: This fixed my problem - thanks - but one observation - On NetBeans restart and (re)build the problem remained - after waiting a few minutes build was successfully - possibly down to being fully cleared by background processing.

Comment: i can't see -> about on my netbeans

Comment: Works perfectly, problem solved. I was hesitant to delete everything because under that folder there are several subdirectories and several files totaling over 76MB, but it is what you have to do. For those of you who might be worrying, NetBeans rebuilds everything once you fire it back up, it just takes a few seconds or so.

Comment: Very annoying bug indeed. Removing only the index folder inside the cache folder is enough, though. That way you don't loose any settings ;-)

Comment: For NetBeans 12.1 on macOS, the cache dir is `Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/NetBeans/12.1`.

Comment: It's still an issue with NB 12.4, but emptying the cache folder and restarting NB is still a valid work-around.

Answer (score 5):

This can also happen if the package name does not match the folder name, or if the package name is omitted. Check the package statement in your source.

Comment: This was my situation, I forgot to add the package name, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

this might be due to 2 classes with the same name in the same package

Answer (score 3):

This also happens if your referencing the erroring class in a separate file in the same package, with the erroring class with an unmatching package path to the file where you are referencing erroring class.

For example 
file 1
some.incorrect.path.package

class_that_is_erroring{
}

file 2
some.correct.path.package

class new_class{

class_that_is_erroring myclass = null;

}

The package paths in both files must match each other and match the file system directory.

Answer (score 1):

If the file name doesn't match the class name, NetBeans 8.0.1 will report this as a duplicate class.

Answer (score 0):

A new answer... In this case, the duplicate class error was confusing. So was part of the next error, but it also pointed to the real problem and the fix.

From my log file:

```
Error 1: a\g\GoodClass error:duplicate class: a.g.GoodClass //Not the problem
Error 2: a\b\BadClass error: cannot access GoodClass        //The problem
         bad source file: a\g\GoodClass                     //No, it's fine
         file does not contain class x.y.GoodClass          //How to fix it
         Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
```

Java reports the first line of *Error 2* because BadClass is using a wildcarded import, either `import x.*;` or `import x.y.*;`. The java compiler found x.y.GoodClass first, so couldn't determine which you really wanted: a.g.GoodClass or x.y.GoodClass.

THE FIX: remove the wildcarded import and add the specific imports you need from library x.y.