# I seem to be getting the error Duplicate class in a java class

Tags: java

I am getting an error that says "duplicate class: (package name).(class name)"
This is the code the line that says the error is "public class Enemy"

```
package rpgdemo;

public class Enemy {
    String name;
    int weaponId;
    int baseAtk;
    int baseDef;
    int hitRate;
    int hp;

    public Enemy(String name,int weaponId, int baseAtk,int baseDef,int hitRate,int hp){
        this.name = name;
        this.weaponId = weaponId;
        this.hp = hp;
        this.baseAtk = baseAtk;
        this.baseDef = baseDef;
        this.hitRate = hitRate;
    }

}
```

Comment: You have another copy of this class in the same package, in the same file or another one. I suggest you use an IDE which should make this clearer.

Comment: Well, do you already have a class Enemy in the package rpgdemo?

Comment: Do you have a class with the same name in your package?

Comment: Change package of `Enemy class` eg `package rpgdemo.model;` and move that java file in that package.

Comment: There is only one java class named Enemy i've also seen a question similar to this and he claims to only have one but still gets the error

Comment: Which tool gives you this error?

Comment: Rename your class to Enemy2.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have another class containing tha same class name. Maybe you have deleted the java file before but the class file still remains. So I suggest you **clean and build the project**.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have same class in the package, try clearing the cache of the editor otherwise change class name. Check this [java - duplicate class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19318704/java-duplicate-class)