# Spring boot+JPA static metamodel - FindBug does not work and throw errors

Tags: java, spring, jpa, findbugs

I use JPA static metamodel in project and my findBug stopped working. I get errors like:

```
Error:(10, 17) java: duplicate class: domain.entity.User_
```

For all autogenerated classess.

I found this answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46190249/4781349)

> Here are some ideas:
>
> Modify the generator to add a (redundant) setter. Implement a FindBugs
>   filter (see http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html) to
>   exclude that specific bug in specific classes or packages. Or
>   generally.

But I do not understand how can I create `myExcludeFilter.xml`(exclude all `Entyty_` classes) and how can I add this file to spring boot.

Comment: Are you using Netbeans ? if yes this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19318704/java-duplicate-class

Comment: Raise a bug on FindBugs if you are sure you don't have duplicate classes